# What is the purpose of connecting the series capacitor to the low side P- channel MOSFET gate?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver

The [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT3752-3752-1.pdf) describes CAOUT as a decoupling capacitor. Not sure how it is so ?

[image]

My guess on the working of the circuit:

1. When AOUT is high, CAOUT is gradually charged with +(on left) and right terminal voltage decreasing to zero.) -Keeping M2 OFF
2. Now when AOUT goes low, CAOUT discharges  - I guess partially through R and CGS of M2. -Turning on M2.  But ultimately the CAOUT charge depletes to zero because of the resistor - **How do we ensure M2 remains turned ON till AOUT goes high again**? Is the resistor just a weak pull down?

Is this a standard circuit to drive a P-channel low side MOSFET with source Grounded?

[image]

Comment: Very likely mistake..Secondary PFET would just short out the supply as drawn. Which reminds us: Have large packs of **salt** handy, when consuming datasheets.

Comment: It's explained more on page 30.

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, could not find anything much regarding the driver Cap

Comment: The flyback is a negative voltage in respect to circuit gnd, so you need to level shift the gate drive negative. M2 only needs to be held on long enough to ‘reset’ the magnetic field so the time constant formed by caout, cgate and the pullup down (pullup??) resistor needs to be considered.

Comment: Imo, the datasheet description of Cout as  "decoupling" capacitor is a typo. I would rather describe it as a "coupling" capacitor.